# How can I solve $(53 \cdot d) \mod 3432 = 1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, modular-arithmetic

I do not know how to calculate this problem

$$(53 \cdot d) \mod 3432 = 1$$

Given this, what is the value of $d$?

Comment: $3432=8\cdot 3\cdot 11\cdot 13$

Comment: (53*d) mod 3432=1, can be rewritten as
3432x+1 = 53*d where x is an integer

Your answer depends on the allowed domain of d, does it it have to be an integer? Otherwise the solution is trivial and simply is a series of points given by d=(3432x+1)/53. If d is an integer, then since 53 is a prime number, you have to find d where 53d-1 contain factors 8⋅3⋅11⋅13. I do not think there is a closed form solution?

Comment: You might want to have a look at the euclidean algorithm.

Answer (score 8):

What you are trying to find is called 'the multiplicative inverse' of $53$ modulo $3432$.

Using [euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm):
$$\begin{align*}
3432 &= 64\cdot53 + 40\\
53&=1\cdot40+13\\
40&=3\cdot13+1
\end{align*}$$

Now, reverse:

$$\begin{align*}
1&=40-3\cdot13\\
1&=40-3\cdot(53-1\cdot40)\\
1&=4\cdot40-3\cdot53\\
1&=4\cdot(3432-64\cdot53)-3\cdot53\\
1&=4\cdot3432 - 259\cdot53
\end{align*}$$

Hence $d=-259$

If you need $d>0$ use $d=3432-259=3173$

I forgot to mention: $\forall k \in \mathbb{Z},d=-259+k\cdot3432$ is a solution.

Comment: "3432 = 64*53+40" Where did the 64 and 40 came from? Same for "1 = 40-3*13" Where did the 40, -3 and 13 came from?

Comment: Try using long division to divide $3432$ by $53$ to give you a quotient and remainder - do it yourself and see what turns up.

Comment: @user8005 For the first part, find the unique integers $a,b$ with $0\le b<53$ such that $3432 = a \cdot 53 + b$ (Division Algorithm). In the second part take the last equation from above ($40=3 \cdot 13+1$) and reorder it so that you have the $1$ on one side. Now plug in the other equations.